# segmentation fault in functions about matrices in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix, malloc

I implemented several functions about matrices related to arrays and pointers and everytime i run the code i get a segmentation fault.
It would be nice if someone could revise my code and maybe explain why this error occurs.

Function 1 should create a dynamically allocated matrix with the correspondent cols and rows. It should also initialize the elements to 0 (i have to use `xmalloc` and cannot use `xcalloc`) and return a pointer to the created matrix.
Function 2 gets an 1D-Array of rows * cols and should create a dynamically allocated matrix of these numbers.
Function 3 should print out a matrix.
Function 4 should free a created matrix.

This is my code

```
struct Matrix {
    int rows; // number of rows
    int cols; // number of columns
    double** data; // a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows; a row is an array of n_cols doubles 
};
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

/**
Creates a zero-initialized matrix of rows and columns matrix.
@param[in] n_rows number of rows
@param[in] n_cols number of columns
@return a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows; a row is an array of n_cols doubles 
*/
Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols) {
    double **m = xmalloc(n_rows * sizeof(double));
    for(int row = 0; row < n_cols; row++){
        m[row] = xmalloc(n_cols * sizeof(double));
    }
    Matrix matrixx = {n_cols, n_rows, m};
    Matrix *pointer;
    pointer = &matrixx;
    return pointer;
}

/**
Creates a zero-initialized matrix of rows and columns matrix.
@param[in] data an array of doubles, ordered row-wise
@param[in] n_rows number of rows
@param[in] n_cols number of columns
@return a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows; a row is an array of n_cols doubles 
*/
Matrix* copy_matrix(double* data, int n_rows, int n_cols) {
    Matrix *pointer = make_matrix(n_rows,n_cols);
    int k = 0;
    double **Matrix = (double **)xmalloc(sizeof(double *) * n_rows);
    for(int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
        Matrix[i] = (double *)xmalloc(sizeof(double ) * n_cols);
    }

    do{
        for(int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
                Matrix[i][j] = data[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }while (k < sizeof(data));
    return pointer;
}

/**
@param[in] m the matrix to print
*/
void print_matrix(Matrix* m) {
    for(int row = 0; row < m->rows; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < m->cols; column++){
            printf("%.f ", m->data[row][column]);
        }
        println();
    }
    println();
}

//@param[in] m the matrix to free

    void free_matrix(Matrix* m) {

   for (int i = 0; i < m->cols; i++)
        free(m->data[i]);

    free(m->data);
     free(m);
    }
```

I tried to allocate the memory with xmalloc in function 1,2 and 4 but somehow this does not work out and i get a segmentation fault error

Comment: The problem is that you are declaring a local variable on the stack (Matrix matrixx = {n_cols, n_rows, m};) then returning a pointer to it. That variable ceases to exist when the function exits, so the pointer is invalid. You need to malloc() memory for the Matrix.

Comment: thank you @pmacfarlane. 
so i have to `xmalloc(sizeof(Matrix));` in front of everything in function2? 
I tried but the error still exists, what size do i have to `malloc`?

Comment: In make_matrix() you need something like: Matrix *pointer = xmalloc(sizeof Matrix);. Then fill in the fields before returning it.

Comment: There are lots of other problems. make_matrix() (if you fix it) allocates all the space for the data. But in copy_matrix(), you call make_matrix(), but then go ahead and xmalloc _more_ space for data, and copy stuff into that. Then you return the matrix you originally made (which has all zero data.)

Comment: I don't know if this is homework and so you have to do it this way, but it seems make_matrix() is redundant. You can do it all with make_matrix_from_1d_array() which would be much simpler and easier to code.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of the make_matrix function, you might want to use only one asterisk because two asterisks mean your pointing to another pointer and I don't see where another pointer would be there

try changing it from this:

```
double **m = xmalloc(n_rows * sizeof(double));
```

to this:

```
double *m = xmalloc(n_rows * sizeof(double));
```

if that doesn't work then than tell me I'll look at the code again and try to spot another error

Comment: Thank you for looking into :) 
When i use one asterisk the compiler says:
`matrix.c:24:16: fatal error: assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'Any' (aka 'void *')
        m[row] = xmalloc(n_cols * sizeof(double));`
I could say that `m[row]` is a double but then i get:
`matrix.c:24:12: fatal error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    double m[row] = xmalloc(n_cols * sizeof(double));`

Comment: Maybe try either taking out the typedef when you init the matrix struct or you put typedef in the matrix definition